Как запретить поиск бота в Телеграмме?
Всем привет!
Есть написанный на Python (pyTelegramBotAPI) телеграмм бот. Он частный и распространяется среди узкого круга коллег.
Как сделать так что бы его нельзя было найти в телеграмме стандартными средствами через поиск посторонними пользователями? (бот распространяется по ссылке QR-коду)
Вариант с аутентификацией не подходит увы....

Никак. Все боты имеют публичное имя, зная которое, бота можно найти через поиск.
Только ограничивать круг пользователей, на команды которых бот будет реагировать по ID. Или, к примеру, использовать какой-нибудь контрольный вопрос, ответ на который знает только сотрудник

Это печально.... Спасибо!
